# jQuery Ajax call - Json unable to be passed to the controller (only null as values) only FormData with processData: false, contentType: false

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am running into a strange situation where my `Reply` method will have all values of my form be null when passed a Json object to the controller, whereas, within the same controller the Create Method is able to without any issues. After trying different methods, I have only been able to successfully pass a FormData object to the Reply method after setting `processData`, and `contentType` to false.

### Things for the Create

```js
$('#commentSectionContainer').on('submit', '#comment-form', function (event) { // submit() has been deprecated, use on('submit') instead
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting normally

    let formData = buildFormData();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Comment/Create',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#commentSectionContainer').html(data); // Replace the container's content
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Error creating comment: ' + errorThrown);
        }        
    });
});
function buildFormData() {
    return {
        text: $('#comment').val(),
        artId: $('#art-id').val(),
        comicId: $('#comic-id').val()
    };
}
```

```html
var disableButton = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? string.Empty : "disabled";
<form id="comment-form" method="post">
    <label for="comment">Add a comment</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Comment</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment" rows="4" style="resize: none; overflow: hidden;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @disableButton>Comment</button>
</form>
```

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateCommentViewModel model)
{
// This model will have its values populated
}
```

### Things for Reply

```js
$('#commentSectionContainer').on('submit', '#reply-form', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var commentId = $(this).find('button[type="submit"]').data('id');
        let formData = buildFoo(commentId); // only a form that is of type FormData will work, not a JSON object

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Comment/Reply',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false, // if set to 'application/json', the controller method will not be able to read the form data
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#commentSectionContainer').html(data); // Replace the container's content
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error creating comment: ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });

function buildFoo(commentId) { //currently working
    let formData = new FormData();
    let text = $('#reply-text-' + commentId).val();
    formData.append('Text', text);
    formData.append('ArtId', $('#art-id').val());
    formData.append('ComicId', $('#comic-id').val());
    formData.append('ParentCommentId', commentId);
    return formData;
}

function buildReplyFormData(commentId) { //tried originally, does not work
    return {
        Text: $('#reply-text-' + commentId).val(),
        ArtId: $('#art-id').val(),
        ComicId: $('#comic-id').val(),
        ParentCommentId: commentId
    };
}
```

*within a for loop*

```html
<div class="reply-area" id="reply-area-@comment.Id" style="display: none;">
    <form id="reply-form" method="post" data-parentId="@comment.Id">
        <input type="hidden" name="parentId" value="@comment.Id" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="reply-text-@comment.Id" name="reply" style="resize: none; overflow: hidden;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save-btn" data-id="@comment.Id">Comment</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary cancel-reply-btn" data-id="@comment.Id">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

```cs
// POST: CommentController/Reply
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Reply(ReplyCommentViewModel model)
{ //for some reason using ModelState.IsValid would fail when a null ComicId was passed.
    if (model.ArtId == null && model.ComicId == null)
        return BadRequest();
}

public class ReplyCommentViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(1000, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int? ArtId { get; set; }
    public int? ComicId { get; set; }
    public int ParentCommentId { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to use `JSON.stringify()`, set `contentType: 'application/json'`, added `data: 'json`. Tried using another ViewModel. I hope this is able to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've provided:

1. In your `Create` method, the form is stringified and then passed to your controller route. That route has [`[FromBody]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) attribute, which instructs your endpoint to read the POST body as a certain type.
2. In your `Reply` method, you are constructing form data manually but no stringifying is happening. Additionally, the corresponding endpoint does not have a `[FromBody]` attribute.

Given that the `Create` method is working, you could start with applying stringification before the formdata is sent to the `Reply` backend. Additionally, add the `[FromBody]` attribute to the corresponding endpoint.

Comment: This adding the `[FromBody]` and stringifying the return from buildReplyFormData(commentId) did work. I did remove the processdata argument and switch back the content type to 'application/json'